# Minimizing the sum of squared differences between integer variables and given values subject to a sum constraint

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

Let $a$ and $p$ be two sets of equal size. $p$ is a set of positive real numbers that sum up to an integer. The objective is to find a set of values $a$ that satisfy the given constraints:

minimize:
$$\sum_i (a_{i} - p_{i}) ^ 2$$
subject to:

$$
\sum_i a_i = \sum_i p_i \\
a_{i} \in \mathbb N
$$

I am new to the field of optimization so I would appreciate some guidance in approaching this problem.

Comment: Is the set of possible integers $a$ predefined, or are you free to select any $n$ integers that sum to the right amount ($n$ being the cardinality of the set of $p$ values)?

Comment: Yes, $a$ can contain arbitrary integers.

Comment: You have an integer program with a convex quadratic objective and a single linear constraint (a quadratic integer program, or QIP). Many IP solvers can handle this type of problem. Why not solve it as a QIP?

Answer (score 1):

Given,

$$\min f(a)=\sum_i (a_{i} - p_{i}) ^ 2$$
$$
\text{Subject to: }\sum_i a_i = \sum_i p_i \\
a_{i} \in \mathbb N
$$

We expand the objective function to become:

$$\min f(a) =\sum_i a_{i}^2 -2\sum_i a_ip_{i}+\sum_i p_i^2$$

The optimal function will reach an optimal solution at $\nabla f(a) = 0$, thus,

$$\nabla f(x) =
\begin{pmatrix}
2a_1 - 2p_1 \\
\vdots \\
2a_n - 2p_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{matrix}
2a_1 - 2p_1 = 0\\
\vdots \\
2a_n - 2p_n = 0
\end{matrix} \rightarrow
\begin{matrix}
2a_1 = 2p_1\\
\vdots \\
2a_n = 2p_n
\end{matrix} \rightarrow
\begin{matrix}
a_1 = p_1\\
\vdots \\
a_n = p_n
\end{matrix}$$

Thus, the min will occur when $a_i = p_i$ for all $i$. Thus,

$$\min f(a=p)=\sum_i (p_{i} - p_{i}) ^ 2 = 0$$
$$
\text{Subject to: }\sum_i p_i = \sum_i p_i \\
$$

This result is expected, as this is this the [sphere function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization#:%7E:text=5-,Sphere,-function), whose global min is at zero. But this solution is the "relaxed" solution, from here, we'll need to use a [branch-and-bound](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Emlavrov/slides/482-spring-2020/slides33.pdf) technique to find integer solutions for the problem in respect to our decision variable $a$. For this problem, this would mean adding additional constraints for each individual $a$ until the sum of $a$ equals the sum of $p$.

For example, consider a relaxed solution of only two variables with $a_1 = 3.5$ and $a_2 = 3.5$, and the sum of $p$ is $7$.

From here we can test two types of constraints that $a_1 \le 3$ (the floor of its relaxed solution) or $a_1 \ge 4$ (the ceil of its relaxed solution). We test each added case until we have no more cases and take the highest feasible case.

So for example, the case of $a_1 \le 3$ would make $a_1=3$ and $a_2=4$, and the case of $a_1 \ge 4$ would make $a_1=4$ and $a_2=3$. Then we would calculate the $f(a)$ of each case and take the best one.

Comment: Could it also be solved with a brute force approach using integer composition? For example we would enumerate each possible integer composition of 7 which would be (7, 0), (1, 6), (2, 5) etc. then evaluating f(a) for each case, then picking the one with the smallest loss. Though I would assume this would be quite costly for large integers/sizes

Comment: It would be time consuming for much larger problems, but it could be done. What I mentioned above in regards to finding the relaxed optimal solution and then using Branch and Bound to find a neighboring optimal integer solution is used often used in practice since we can terminate early once we find a parent-case, feasible solution that's better than everything that inherits from it, so we can eliminate a lot of cases than exhaustively go through them all. Here's a good lecture presentation on it: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~mlavrov/slides/482-spring-2020/slides33.pdf

Comment: If this answers your question, btw, please click the check under the vote!